# Javascript Object Question

Tags: javascript, object, global

I'm a beginner w/ Javascript. I'm looking at the following code that someone else wrote:

```
function MeetingPage()
{
   MeetingPage.colors = new Object();
}

...

var meeting = new MeetingPage();
```

From what I've seen, I believe that the MeetingPage function creates an object that later someone holds onto in meeting. What is the MeetingPage.colors? Is the MeetingPage prefix some kind of global? Is it a "this" pointer of some kind?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually you see `this` there, I'm not sure if that will work the same (or even if it intends to).

Comment: The code seems rather weird. Essentially the colors property will always be changed each time you invoke `MeetingPage` as a constructor or function. Also the colors property won't even be linked to an instance of `MeetingPage`.

Comment: How would you link the property to an instance?

Comment: with `this.` instead of `MeetingPage.`

Comment: To make it instance-based instead, it would be `this.colors = {};` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually just bad code.  `MeetingPage.colors = new Object();` is setting a property called `colors` on the `MeetingPage` **function**, i.e:

```
function MeetingPage(){ }
MeetingPage.colors = {};
```

Which is perfectly valid since all functions in JavaScript are objects.  The problem is that if you have multiple instances of meeting page:

```
var meeting1 = new MeetingPage();
var meeting2 = new MeetingPage();
```

The code you posted will reset `colors`.  It should either should be written as `this.colors = {}`, or it should be set ***outside*** of the function as in my first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This talk was really helpful when I got into different object patterns in javascript. Example code is included in the second link (the video introduces it).

http://alexsexton.com/?p=94

http://alexsexton.com/inheritance/demo/

http://alexsexton.com/?p=51

Of course, you should also definitely read [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This is the JavaScript syntax for creating  *Class Properties*.  Note, it is a **class** property not an **instance** property, that means it is shared across all instances of the class. (If you know C++ this is like a class static) However, I didn't think it was valid to put a class property inside the constructor itself. I would think that every time a new MeetingPage is created the colors class property will get wiped out.